# Excel Data Manipulation with alphanumberic data

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel. We can say that column 1 and column 2. Both columns have alphanumeric data i want to minus column 1 from column 2. How can i do that. 
Example:

```
column 1     column two   result column

ab              ab        ad
ac              ac
ad
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you draw the conclusion that `ab-ab=ad`?

Comment: It's not a "minus." Pretty sure he wants to list just the values in column 1 that do not exist in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are more sophisticated/cleaner ways to do this, but I'd enter this formula into column C (update your ranges accordingly to capture each list), and then sort the result column:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$4)=0,A1,"")
```

This compares the list in `$A$1:$A$8` to the list in `$B$1:$B$4` and places the "differences" in the result column C.  I'm assuming that sorting is permissible.  But like I said, there are VBA solutions that could do this a little more cleanly.